# Is there a way to ignore header line when importing csv file for mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to insert some records into my mysql database from a csv file in S3 bucket.
However, the column header gets inserted as a row as well. I want to skip it.

```
create table t (id varchar(10),Name Varchar(10))
```

Later, I am trying to insert records into this table via
replace statement, and I don't see an option to ignore first record there.
I can't use 'select * from t limit 1,5000'

Comment: Most CSV-to-dbms import features have a way to skip the first few lines of a CSV file. In `LOAD DATA INFILE`, it's `SKIP 1 LINES`.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear before, but im inserting file from s3, I tried load command, but its not working from S3